# React dynamic search/filter returns undefined

Tags: reactjs, map-function, react-state

I'm trying to create a dynamic search that can be sorted by title or date. Right now my code is focusing on title, and once I have that working I will duplicate it to make the date work too. However, right now, my filter method is not working and I don't know how to fix it without breaking my map function.

I am currently getting **"Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined"**. It is referring to the `newsItem.title`, but I'm not sure how to fix it.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import labNewsJson from '../json/labNews.json';
import '../styles/News.css';
var moment = require('moment');

const newsList = labNewsJson['news'];

class News extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            search: ''
        };
    }

updateSearch(event) {
    this.setState({ search: event.target.value }) 
}
render() {
    // let filteredNews = this.props.newsList;
            newsList.sort(function(a, b) {
                var dateA = new Date(a.date), dateB = new Date(b.date);
                return dateB - dateA;
            });

            let filteredNews = newsList.filter((newsItem) => {
                return newsItem.title.toLowerCase().includes(this.state.search.toLowerCase())
                }
            );
            const news = filteredNews.map((newsItem, index) => {
                return <div className='newsContainer' key={index}><h3>{newsItem.title}</h3><p><strong>{newsItem.description}</strong><br></br>{moment(newsItem.date).format("LL")}</p></div>
            });


    return (

            <div className='container'>
                <div className='pageTitle'><h1>Lab News</h1></div>

                 <div>{news}</div>
            <input type="text" value={this.state.search} onChange={this.updateSearch.bind(this)} />

            </div>
        );
 }
}

export default News;
```

Comment: please add the json file

Comment: Oh my goodness, that made me recheck the JSON file and I realize, I use "title" but haven't yet entered a title field as the News page is practice right now. When I switch it to `newsItem.title` to `newsItem.description`, things work fine. Thank you, clearly I just need a second pair of eyes!

Comment: great  happy to help